# How to hide recent item from recycle bin layout

Tags: page-layout, recycle-bin, recent-item

I want to hide recent items from page layout. I made changes on home page layout, the recent item get hidden from the home page. But I click on the recycle bin all the recent items are getting displayed. How can I hide it form recycle bin page layout. Where edit recycle bin. Please guide me how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few screens which are not customizable. Unfortunately, you won't be able to remove the recent items list from here.